# Iterate through appended items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

### Question

I have a form that uses jQuery for magic. On that form is a button `Add Account`. That button appends fields `Account` and `Amount` and also another button `Remove Account` (which if you can guess, removes those two fields). This all works nicely...

On the same form there is another field `Salary`, which I would like to compare with the total of all the `Amount` fields. The problem is when I use jQuery's `$.each()` to iterate through the `Amount` fields it only recognizes those fields that were present in the DOM when the page loaded, and not the newly added fields.

How can I iterate through these appended `Amount` fields? (Or maybe there is a better to do this altogether?)

What I'm doing now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#form').on('keyup', '.amount', balanceAmountsWithSalary);
});

var balanceAmountsWithSalary = function(){
  var salary = parseInt($('#salary').val(),10);
  var total = 0;
  $('#accounts .account').each(function(){
    var amount = parseInt($(this).find('.amount').val(),10);
    total += amount;
  });
  if (total === salary) {
    $('#accounts .account').each(function(){
      // Do some stuff to each input.amount located in div.account
    });
  } else {
    $('#accounts .account').each(function(){
      // Do some BAD stuff to each input.amount located in div.account
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks!

---

### Answer

So it probably would've been more helpful to include the rest of my code at the outset as the problem was a simple error in the add account event. I mislabeled my container class adding an "s" to name of the appended items only. In any case thats for the comments! Posting an example on jsFiddle helped me find this error, so [here is the thing in action](http://jsfiddle.net/pn7hb/) in case you were wondering.

Comment: Can you post a live demo that reproduces the problem? Try http://jsbin.com

Comment: Either that, or show the rest of the code. The "Add Account" code is missing. Also it might helpful to show what the html looks like after an account has been added.

Comment: If you can't iterate items that were dynamically added, then it's probably because they don't have the right classes on them to match your selector.  The only way we could help you with that is to see what the code looks like that adds items to the page.

Comment: The form has one `Account` and `Amount` field present when the page loads. The problem is I'm not able to iterate through the appended fields. The appended fields still trigger the event as the event is delegated and these items don't need to be present when the DOM is loaded the first time.

Answer (score 0):

As HTML code and code of Dynamic adding inputs are not provided, I have edited an existing Fiddler to get total of dynamic added input field.

In this fiddler simple for loop is used to calculate total amount.

[Here is a fiddler which might help you.](http://jsfiddle.net/JF38y/33/)

```
//button click get total
$('#GetTotal').click( function(event){
        var tableID = "NewInvoiceTable";
        GetTotalAmount(tableID);
        return false;
    });
//Get total
function GetTotalAmount(tableID)
{
    var i = $('#' + tableID + ' tr').length;
    alert("Total Rows -" + i);
    var TotAmt = 0;
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        TotAmt += parseInt($('#TotalInline-' + j).val());
    }
    alert("Total Amount - " + TotAmt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however your example is slightly different to what I'm trying to do.